# How do I replace a range with another range in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I want to replace a range of elements in a vector by a single other element (built from that range, but it doesn't matter). I'd like to do so without erasing first and inserting then, for all subsequent elements would me moved twice.

I figured we could generalize that with the replacement of a range by another range, whatever their sizes. Replace an empty range with something and you get insert. Replace something with an empty range and you get erase.

Anyways `replace` seems not to do that. It replaces all or some elements in a rage with copies of the given element. No moving around.

`swap_ranges` swaps elements one by one, no erase or insert either.

Have I missed an `algorithm` for that? Maybe a member function?

Maybe I should use `list` then?

Comment: I also don't know an stl-algorithm for that. They mostly have the form `n->1`, `1->n` or `n->n`, not `n->m` (where `n` is the number of elements before and `m` is the number after) for `n!=m`.

Comment: Did you try writing a function to do what you want?  The successful effort might help you recognize some as yet undiscovered terminology, and perhaps improve your search efforts ... and in the meantime, you can use your function until you can find what you want.

Comment: There's nothing in `algorithm` for this, but it shouldn't be hard to write your own. If the new range is shorter than the old range (as would be in your case except in the edge case of the old range being empty), this translates to `std::copy` followed by `std::vector::erase`. If the new range is larger, this translates to `std::copy` followed by `std::vector::insert`. Sounds pretty simple to me.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking (maybe a sample input and output would help), but my first thought is to use `std::transform`

Answer (score 1):

> I want to replace a range of elements in a vector by a single other element

As far as I know, there is no algorithm for this in standard library. But it can be fairly simply be built on top of the existing ones: Remove all except first of the range. Assign the element that wasn't removed. In the special case of empty range, insert instead of assigning. Return iterator to the beginning of the removed elements (iterator to end in case nothing was removed) so that the caller can erase them.

> I figured we could generalize that with the replacement of a range by another range

This works pretty much the same as the single insert variation, but is more complex. Replace assignment with `std::copy`, and take into consideration that there is also a case where you both assign (copy) and insert a subrange depending on lengths of the input ranges.

The order assignment, remove, insert does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is an algorithm that can't be done with "just iterators".
To change the size of the underlying sequence, you need to be able to call `insert` or `erase` on the underlying container.

So even though you might want to write something like:

```
template <typename Iter1, typename Iter2>
void replaceRange (Iter1 s_first, Iter1 s_last, Iter2 d_first, Iter2 d_last);
```

it won't ever work (except for the cases where the sizes are the same)

Comment: Could be a member function. `myVec.replace(it1, end1, it2, end2);`